# Seaside - how to get the full url while in a session

Tags: http, smalltalk, seaside

I am developing an application that will serve multiple customer-organizations, each of them should be given access based on a fixed url. Example: `domain/myapp/CustomerOrg1`

Previously I always registered a new WAComponent-subclass for each of these entry-points. That does work but there has to be a better solution, I would like a single component-class to find out which URL the request uses (to then respond with the customer-org's homepage)

I tried:

- registering a WARequestHandler-subclass; and it allows me to find out the full path (incl. `/CustomerOrg1`) but I am outside of any session and don't know how to get into one.
- registering a WAComponent-subclass as `/myapp`, and it works in that it also handles `/myapp/CustomerOrg1` automatically, however when I try to find out the URL used (by `self session url inspect`) it claims to be only the base-url (`/myapp`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
self requestContext request uri
```

and if you are not in a component but any object you can do

```
WACurrentRequestContext value request uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the uri you get in the answer by Norbert is in a production environment a value that has already been processed, and possibly modified, by your (Apache/nginx/etc) webserver responsible for static content and load balancing.